# Configure different appsettings POCO based on the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a dictionary of settings in my appsettings.json , they will be translated to the following class

```
    public class SiteSettings
    {
        public Dictionary<SettingsKey, Settings> Options { get; set; }

    }
```

```
  public class Settings
  {
        public string Option1 { get; set; }        
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
  }
```

And json file looks like this

```
{

    "SiteSettings": {
      "Options": {
        "setting1": {
          "Option1": "test"
        },
        "setting2": {
          "Option1": "test2"

        }
      }
    }
}
```

I need to configure Settings POCO based on the HTTP request!

in ConfigureServices method I have

```
           services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("SiteSettings:Options:settings1"));
```

Lets say I have a query string in my URL which carries the settings key name (settings1 or settings2). The issue is ConfigureServices runs before even any page is requested, which is expected as it configurea and set services before the app runs.

Just wondering if it is even possible to some how Configure Settings POCO based on the coming request!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get data from appsettings after you get query string.Here is a demo:

Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }
```

Controller:

```
IConfiguration _iconfiguration;
        public Test1Controller(IConfiguration iconfiguration)
        {
            _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
        }
        public IActionResult TestAppsetting(string appsetting) {
            var s = _iconfiguration.GetSection("SiteSettings:Options:"+ appsetting);
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]